# How to loop multiple arrays and display the values using vba?

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, outlook

How to loop multiple arrays and display the values?

Example Array:

- num = (1, 2, 3)
- name = (Tesa, John, Mike)
- tag = (tag1, tag2, tag3)

Result:

- 1.... Tesa.... tag1
- 2.... John.... tag2
- 3.... Mike.... tag3

It's not efficient when I'm doing it like this as the array might contain 1 or more values. I can't keep on adding list4, list5, list6, and so on.

```
list1 = num(1) + ".... " + name(1) + ".... " + tag(1) + "<br/>"
list2 = num(2) + ".... " + name(2) + ".... " + tag(2) + "<br/>"
list3 = num(3) + ".... " + name(3) + ".... " + tag(3) + "<br/>"

Debug.Print list1 + list2 + list3
```

Comment: You only need to loop once to the `Ubound` of the largest array. Then if you wanted you can create a new array that you add to each loop. For example you use `For i = Lbound(num) To Ubound(num)` then you can make `list` an array and do `list(i) = ...` However your problem is more of what will happen when the arrays don't have the same amount of data in them. How will you solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1 (with Array())

```
Sub test1()
    Dim Num, Name, Tag, i
    Num = Array(1, 2, 3)
    Name = Array("Tesa", "John", "Mike")
    Tag = Array("tag1", "tag2", "tag3")
        
    For i = 0 To UBound(Num)
        Debug.Print Join(Array(Num(i), Name(i), Tag(i)), ".... ")
    Next
End Sub
```

### Option 2 (with Collection and Array())

```
Sub test2()
    Dim col As New Collection, i, a
    col.Add Array(1, 2, 3)
    col.Add Array("Tesa", "John", "Mike")
    col.Add Array("tag1", "tag2", "tag3")
    ' add any number of arrays into the collection
        
    ReDim a(1 To col.Count)
    For j = 0 To UBound(col(1))
        For i = 1 To col.Count: a(i) = col(i)(j): Next
        Debug.Print Join(a, ".... ")
    Next
End Sub
```

Output:

```
1.... Tesa.... tag1
2.... John.... tag2
3.... Mike.... tag3
```

Comment: These two options helped me. Thanks

Comment: By the way, on Option 1, I assigned the Join to a variable but I only got the last result. How do you get all the output and assign to a single variable for display?

Comment: Before the loop make `buf=""`. Then, within the loop make `buf=buf & Join(Array(Num(i), Name(i), Tag(i)), ".... ") & VbLf`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create variable names dynamically that I am aware of. I would use multidimensional array for this so instead of `List3 = Num(3)` you'd have `Lists(2,2)`

```
'3 Lists with 3 entries per person but with 0 based array we declare it as 2,2
Dim Lists(2, 2) As String
'Declare counters for 2 For loops needed
Dim i As Long
Dim b As Long
'String to concatenate 3 entries for each person + formating
Dim Str As String
'Polulate array
Lists(0, 0) = 1
Lists(0, 1) = "Tesla"
Lists(0, 2) = "Tag 1"
Lists(1, 0) = 2
Lists(1, 1) = "John"
Lists(1, 2) = "Tag 2"
Lists(2, 0) = 3
Lists(2, 1) = "Mike"
Lists(2, 2) = "Tag 3"
'Loop through each person
For i = 0 To 2
    'Reset string at the begining of each loop
    Str = ""
    'Loop through each field for each person
    For b = 0 To 2
        'Add required dots as spacers if current field isn't the first one
        If b > 0 Then
            Str = Str + ".... "
        End If
        Str = Str + Lists(i, b)
    Next b
    'Once the fields are done add the <br/>
    Str = Str + "<br/>"
    'Do stuff with whole record before next iteration
    Debug.Print Str
Next i
```

... or if you get the arrays you get and you know they are all the same size you could just

```
For i = 0 To UBound(num)
    Debug.Print CStr(num(i)) + ".... " + name(i) + ".... " + tag(i) + "<br/>"
Next i
```